# In a Docker application, How to maintain add-on application when upgrading the base image(Code-server)?

Tags: docker, code-server

I have been using code-server for almost a year. It is a web-based programming IDE running on docker.
https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/code-server

And I use it to develope JAVA and PYTHON. Therefore I install JVM and python runtime, also many PIP packages into the container.

I know docker container are not supposed to store application, and custom data are best maintained in a mounted volumn seperated from the container.

But as a programming IDE situation, those programs are subjected to change and accumulated on day-to-day usage.

It comes to headache when upgrading the base image, because those JVM, python packages, and other middleware needed to be re-installed.

I did some reading about DOCKER inheritance and watchtower, but I still not quite sure those are correct approach.

So I would like to ask if there are solutions to keep my newly added programs in the container when upgrading the code-server image?

Comment: Create a custom image using FROM <the base image> and RUN statements to pip install your requirements
Use that image, but indeed if you are running local, mount a local volume to store your artifacts, or use git to push to an external repository.
when you want to update the base image, update the FROM statement to the new base image and rebuild your custom image.

Answer (score 0):

For the JVM and Java/Python packages, mount a volume. I would also keep your working project directories in a mounted volume (In addition to your VCS of choice). From here, watchtower can takeover and handle the updates. If you are using Git, I would **not** recommend storing your packages/binaries in Git.